# Issue with relinquishing Java threads in UNIX using ExecutorService.awaitTermination()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

There seems some issue running the Java ExecutorService (java.util.concurrent) in a UNIX environment. This issue doesnt replicate in Windows...

Issue: The pool takes unduly long time to terminate:

The program typically creates a new pool:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
```

Submits tasks to it:

```
executorService.execute(thread);
```

Marks it closed for new tasks, so no more tasks can be submitted:

```
 executorService.shutdown();
```

Makes a blocking call to terminate the threads:

```
executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Now, as I can make out from the logs, I can see that the threads are finished with their jobs in very little time. Even though the thread pool takes 2 hours to finish all the tasks, the `awaitTermination()` call suggests the pool having taken entire timeout period of 10 hours, implying that the pool didn’t relinquish the threads once it is done with them.

Did not get any forums which deal with this issue/ aspects of multithreading specific to the unix environment. Have anyone come across this situation before & know how to overcome that?

Comment: And what do your threads DO? Why pass an instance of a thread for that matter, and not a Runnable or Callable? Are your threads daemons?

Comment: The threads execute only 3-4 lines - which dont take much of time... They only hit a url each & inspect response headers. That is not an issue. I can clearly make out that each thread is done with its task in very negligible amount of time. The issue is after the awaitTermination() returns (after full timeout period), I see log statment saying it took 10 hours!

Comment: This still doesn't answer my two questions: why pass instances of `Thread`s instead of `Runnable`s or `Callable`s? Are you thread daemon threads?

Comment: Please post a minimal code fragment that works correctly under Windows but fails under UNIX.

Comment: @fge- No, they are not daemon threads. I am passing my thread instance (which implements Runnable). BTW, how much difference does that make- if I pass Runnable, instead of Thread?? Here's the code fragment:                  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

while(resultSet.next()) {
 Runnable thread = new MyThread(resultSet.get(1));
 executorService.execute(thread);
}
executorService.shutdown();
try {
 executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 executorService.shutdownNow();
}

Comment: You are creating one `Thread` per line of your `ResultSet`? That may indeed screw up your system. Don’t create a `Thread` where a simple `Runnable` is required.

Comment: @Holger- Yes, am creating one Runnable per line of resultset. How's Runnable to be used differently than a Thread?? I did not understand... They are both used to create asynchronous thread ultimately, I believe. Can you elucidate further?